# json parser failing the first time

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

the asp code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#abc').click(function fu() {
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data1,gh,kl)
                    {
                        console.log(kl.response);
                        var json = $.parseJSON(kl.response);
                        console.log(json[0].uid);

                    },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        }
            });      
        });
   });    

</script>
```

the handler code handling button event

```
 public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        balcl obj = new balcl();
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var res = obj.getUID();
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(res));
    }
```

Why does my code fail the first time but works fine the second time I click?

Comment: What is the error you get? Where? What are the responses from the server?

Comment: On click one                                                                                         ->Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
On click 2
-> [{"uid":4,"uname":"hari"},{"uid":5,"uname":"hi"}]
-> 4

Comment: That suggests that res is null. Debug the application to see that `obj.getUID()`actually returns something. Also, `getUID()`as a function name would suggest returning one UID, not an array/list of objects with UIDs.

Comment: Then how does it work the second time?its working perfectly on the second click.

Comment: That is for you to determine by debugging the return value of it the first time and seeing why that method returns null, if it indeed does.

Comment: ah..! got it working,I had not set async:false in my code.I believe browser creates multiple threads for every ajax call and the tread was getting terminated as it took time.Thanks a lot. :)